# When is a segmentation fault guaranteed?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm learning c++ and I've learned that segfaults can happen because of undefined behaviour.  Are there ever cases though, where segfaults are guaranteed to happen?  Or is it always undefined behaviour?

Comment: It might be guaranteed with a specific compiler on a specific platform, but C++ itself doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: reading from null is likely to do it `std::cout << *(int*)nullptr;` but its not a guarantee

Comment: Segfaults are guaranteed to happen when you try to access memory that process does not have access to. At least, I hope they are...

Comment: C++ does not have a concept of "segmentation fault". So C++ itself cannot possibly guarantee it. It is a platform-specific/implementation-specific detail.

Comment: you can call `std::raise(SIGSEGV)` to raise an invalid memory access [signal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/csignal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segfaults occur in an operating system with memory protection when you attempt to read or write memory that you do not have permission to access — special values like `nullptr`, memory reserved for the OS, or memory of another process.

Because segfaults are raised by the OS, they are an inherently platform-specific concept. Something that causes a segfault on Windows will not necessarily cause a segfault on e.g. AmigaOS. The C++ standard, being platform-agnostic, doesn't even mention segfaults.

On modern OSes with memory protection, you can always be assured a segfault when you access memory that you don't own. Dereferencing `nullptr` will cause it for sure. Accessing a random address is probably not within your process's address space, so that will likely cause a segfault (hence why accessing uninitialized pointers or dangling pointers often causes a segfault). On AmigaOS or classic Mac OS, which lack memory protection, you won't get a segfault from accessing random pointers. Instead, you could overwrite the memory of the OS or another process (which would likely be disastrous).

Basically, a segfault is an OS concept, not a C++ concept, so what you can do to cause one in C++ depends on what you're running on.

Comment: You _cannot_ be sure that attempting to dereference null will cause segmentation fault on new systems either, because compilers can and do remove the deference instruction if they can prove that it's always null. Undefined behavior is never reliable.